# Eclipse : Avoid test resources during application launch

Tags: eclipse, maven, logback

I have a maven webapp project imported into eclipse 3.4 with logback(1.0.9) logging. There is:

> - src/main/resources/logback.xml
> - src/test/resources/logback-test.xml

When I launch the webapp in Tomcat, because of the order Logback finds the configuration file, logback-test.xml is always loaded. I want the logback.xml to be loaded, instead, for the application launch and use the logback-test.xml only for the test classes.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Strange, in a packaged WAR the test resources should not have made their way into the WAR.  Are you sure your test directory hasn't somehow been configured as one of the source directories?  If not, please post your folder structure and POM.

Comment: ".. Are you sure your test directory hasn't somehow been configured as one of the source directories?.." - Not sure. How do I confirm?

Comment: Please post your folder structure and POM file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was improper configuration of the locations for deployment into Tomcat. This can be configured in Eclipse from

> **Project Properties** > **Deployment Assembly**